# Child div is scrollable, but body's height still increases when adding content within child

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a `div` in my HTML page that has `overflow-y: scroll;`, and this appears to work just fine.

But when I add content to this scrollable child, my page's `body` increases in height such that now the whole page is scrollable. But scrolling the page down shows empty background-color space.

It's as if the `body` is allocating space for the content inside the scrollable child, despite the child being scrollable and thus not requiring the body to allocate this space.

Is there a style property that causes this, and is there a style property (or removal of a property) that can fix it?

---

EDIT:
As a clue, my scrollable child element has `display: flex;`, and when I change it to `display: block;`, the new position it has extends exactly to the bottom of the extra space the `body` has. So it's as if the `body` is behaving as if the child `div` has `display: block;`, ignoring the it's actual `display` value.

Comment: Please add the code in the question instead of linking to it

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it, you have a child element inside of a parent element. You want the child element to be scrollable, but the parent element to not be. Is that right?

In many cases, only adding overflow-y: scroll; to the child element  might not be enough.

Try adding overflow-y: hidden; to the parent element, and also set a max-height to your child element.

That should fix the issue.
Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks! That's close to what I want, but I don't want to stop the body from being scrollable _at all_. If something visibly extends down past the bottom of the viewport, I want to be able to scroll the body down to it. It's just that this scrollable child's content does NOT visibly extend past the bottom (it does extend down there, just not visibly), so I don't want it to make the body scroll.

Comment: Maybe you should add overflow:hidden; to the child element and see what happens?

Comment: That takes away the child scroll, but the body still scrolls. The problem is that the child's contents do technically extend far down (I can see their position down there by using Inspect Element), but since they are invisible I wish they had no effect on the body's length / scrollability.

Comment: Yes, and in theory, overflow: hidden should remove any element outside of the parent element's boundaries. Other than that I am blank, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `position: relative` along with your other CSS properties to your DIV's class, body's height should not increase. Following code is working for me.

```
.YOUR-CLASS {
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```